# How to define array type in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am using variables of the following type in typescript:

```
[[string, string], string][]
```

Is there a way to define this as type so I don't have to repeat this definition everywhere in my code?

Answer (score 4):

You can define a `type`:

```
type stringTuple = [[string, string], string][];
```

And then later use it similar to how you would use a class or interface:

```
var array: stringTuple;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's hard to find this in the typescript documentation. I would expect at least a language reference with an index of keywords.