# How to define a data type in typescript for arrays?

Tags: arrays, class, typescript, types, constructor

I am trying to define an array type to basically look like this:

```
[
  {
    name: string,
    comment: string
  },
  {
    name: string,
    comment: string
  }
]
```

but it needs to work no matter how many comments there are in the array.

I found some examples with set lengths like this guy [How to define array type in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871398/how-to-define-array-type-in-typescript)

But I can't get it to work for what I am doing, here is the context:

```
class Post{
  person: string;
  bird: string;
  content: string;
  image: string;
  comments: Array<MyType>;
  score: number;
  grade: number;
  constructor(p: string, b: string, c: string, i: string = '', cm: Array<MyType> = []) {
    this.person = p
    this.bird = b
    this.content = c
    this.image = i
    this.comments = cm
    this.score = 0
    this.grade = this.score + this.cm.length
  }
}
```

how should I define the type MyType?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Post{
  person: string;
  bird: string;
  content: string;
  image: string;
  comments: Array<{name:string, comment:string}>;
  score: number;
  grade: number;
  constructor(p: string, b: string, c: string, i: string = '', cm: Array<{name:string, comment:string}> = []) {
    this.person = p
    this.bird = b
    this.content = c
    this.image = i
    this.comments = cm
    this.score = 0
    this.grade = this.score + this.cm.length
  }
}
```

Comment: okay so you only define the types of what will be in the aray not the whole structure of the array?

Comment: Yes, that's how you emulate type safety checking in javascript, you just need to tell it the "shape" of the objects your list contains

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer interface ovre class

```
interface Post{
  person: string;
  bird: string;
  content: string;
  image: string;
  comments: Array<Comment>;
  score: number;
  grade: number;
}
interface Comment{
    name : string;
    comment:string;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't convert `Post` as an interface as the constructor for `Post` class from the OP has some logic in it. `Comment` should be fine as an interface though.

Comment: if you are using models(custom datatype) you can go with the interface. Writing class and creating a instance will trouble some time when instance remains unchanged.

Comment: The constructor an the logic inside it from the OP implies that `Post` is not only just to provide structure (where interfaces should be preferred), but also to create an actual instance of `Post` which you can't with interfaces.

Comment: i just wanted an organized way to create sample data for an angular 4 app i am making, its still not compiling correctly so i decided to just make the api first